# Поиск латинских символов по строкам

Tags: c++, файлы

Всем добрый день, как мне сделать так, чтобы поиск символов латиницы происходил не по символам, а по строкам, и чтобы строка, которая имеет латинские символы исключалась в 2 файле. Прикрепил мой код, заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    ifstream file1("file1.txt");
    ofstream file2("file2.txt");
    if (!file1) 
    { 
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла";       
        return 0; 
    }
    if (file1 && file2 ) 
    {
        char t;
        if (!file2)
        {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла";
            return 0;
        }

        while (file1.get(t)) 
        {
            if (!isalpha(t))
                file2.put(t);
        }
        
    }
    cout << "Успешно скопировано" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Читайте сразу строки - `fgets()` - и работайте с ними...

Comment: Как и написал Harry, вы можете использовать функцию [fgets](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/fgets) для считывания файла построчно. Например вот так может выглядеть ваш цикл: `while(fgets(buf, bufsize, file))`. Функция [isalpha](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/isalpha) принимает не строку, а только 1 символ. Так что вам нужно пройтись по считанной из файла строке и если вы найдете латинский символ, то закончить проход по строке и перейти к следующей, а если вы прошли всю строку, то добавить её во 2-ой файл.